Action should be taken about VictoriaMetrics's spamming
I'm doing some research about Prometheus setup these days, and something very much annoying and frustrating is happening to me.
On lots of posts and questions on stackoverflow and other places like Reddit, I'm facing some answers that are shamelessly promoting VictoriaMetrics. This promotion is usually hidden in some normal discussion, that is undetectable for normal users or people that are new to the concept. Things like "I have used the product and it was the best!" or "You can do what you are going to do with Prometheus with VictoriaMetrics, and it is incredibly awesome!".
These messages are like normal answers, but they are actually misleading, self-promotional and spam trying to deceive people into using whatever that product is.
I see the account posting these is suspended until the next month, but it would not be enough. These spam messages already exist in the community and are misleading people.
I do not know what enforcement measures can be taken to remove them from the system, but I think something has to be done about it, along with some measures to prevent similar issues from happening in the future.

Do you have any links to said posts? Charcoal works to remove spam from all sites across the network, but it does require manual intervention when posts sneak through. They can be reported in the chat room Charcoal HQ if not caught.

Like https://stackoverflow.com/a/71573701/1919959 (and many other answers by the author). You can see how much hidden and normal-looking it is.

I note that in this instance, they specifically state that they are one of VictoriaMetrics' developers. By SE standards, it's not spam if you disclose your affiliation and fully explain how the product solves the problem, but any answers where they mention VM without disclosing their affiliation (or just say "use VictoriaMetrics!" without explaining how) should indeed be deleted as spam.

@Ahmad the author of your example above is already suspended. When it's useful, I don't think such things should be deleted, it's not outright spam. If you notice a pattern though (e.g. several users promoting same product) you can custom flag one of the posts, carefully explain, and mods can handle it.

@ShadowWizard There is the user who posted comment spam under that answer...

On your note for reddit: there are services that offer llm generated comments to "subtly" place adds all over reddit threads. It's only going to get worse from here

@Starship deleted now so can't see, but it's the same concept: bunch of employees, led by the CTO of the company, promoting it on Stack Overflow without giving attribution, but while also giving otherwise decent answers. This isn't something that should be handled by ordinary users,  but rather moderators, and they handled it nicely IMO, by suspending some, and likely removing posts which weren't helpful enough to justify letting them stay.

All in all, looks like the request here is to delete all the posts, and I don't agree with that.
